# How to set AWS ELB name for nginx-ingress using the helm-chart

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to set the load-balancer names created by the [nginx-ingress helm](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) chart. I've reviewed most of the annotations that are [listed here](https://github.com/kubernetes/legacy-cloud-providers/blob/master/aws/aws.go#L101-L211). Specifically, I've tried all of the below configurations;

```
controller:
  name: kubernetes-nginx-controller

service:
  annotations:    
    kubernetes.io/service-name: "kubernetes-nginx-controller"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags: "Name=kubernetes-nginx-controller"
```

I am still seeing my AWS dashboard below.

[image]

And this makes me anxious while looking at the ELB dashboard. Seems like this should be very straightforward to achieve, and I'm probably missing something, but couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of this GitHub Thread [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/29789) it is not possible to set an ELB name at the moment.

Comment: Oh wow, I never thought this would be the case. Thanks for pointing out.